# Can I keep Where-Object output with multiple -or criteria in the same order when source data is in a different order?

Tags: powershell

I'm a newcomer to PowerShell scripting and the code below is my first script ever; the result of many attempts. It does what I want it to, though I'm having trouble with a small part of it - the output order of the "where-object" command.

I'm using -or to return three variables I'm interested in and compare to the output of the same script ran previously. The problem is, the order of variables in the source can be different. One day it will return "Var1"; "Var2"; "Var3" and another will return "Var3"; "Var1"; "Var2". This becomes a problem when I compare the two outputs and they get flagged, but the only change is the order.

I've tried googling solutions and seeing if there is some filtering I missed, or the order of operations, but some of the information out there is inaccessible to a newbie.

This is my code:

```
# Asks to enter when the previous script was run, for comparison later.
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$previousdate)

# Scrapes urls based on links.txt, outputs chosen parameters to a text file with today's date.
ForEach ($line in Get-Content links.txt) {
    (((wget $line).Content).split(",") |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Contains("var1") -or $_.Contains("var2") -or $_.Contains("var3")
    } ) -Join "" |
            Out-File "$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).txt" -Append
};

# Parameters specify which file to compare to today's output (created above).
$old = Get-Content ".\$previousdate.txt"
$path = Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd
$today = Get-Content ".\$path.txt"

# Run comparison between the previous scrape (specified by user) to file created today.
Compare-Object $old $today |
    out-file "compare $(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).txt" -width 500
```

During the last step, because the source changes, the comparison occasionally spits out that "var1 var2 var3" is different to "var1 var3 var2". While technically correct, I only want to see differences where the variables themselves are different, not just the order.

Is there a (relatively) SIMPLE way of preserving the order of variables in out-file to be the same as the order specified every time, regardless of the source order? Is there a better way of doing this?

I'm really enjoying powershell and keen to learn more, but please keep in mind that I'm still learning. I'd really appreciate all answers, but if you can explain why it works that would be spectacular.

Thank you!

---

Some additional info:
Each variable comes in the format "AAA:123" and the AAA will never change. I kinda solved the comparison issue by throwing in a "| Sort" before the "-Join" which keeps the variables in the same order every time, though it feels like a band-aid.

To redirect the question slightly: I would like the variables in the output to be in a SPECIFIC order, rather than alphabetic. I still haven't figured out how to do that, though I'm investigating using `ForEach-Object`, as suggested by the lovely @Lee_Dailey.

Comment: i don't see anything in your code that would change the order ... _except_ for the source having the items in a different order. so ... where is the sequence change appearing? have you confirmed that the difference is NOT in the source?

Comment: It IS the source order that's changing. My apologies for not making that clearer. I'm looking for a way to format the output to always be in the same order, regardless of the source order.  

I've considered throwing in a sort-object before the -join, but I'm not sure how to force it to be the same each time yet...

Comment: you could replace your `Where-Object` with a `ForEach-Object` and do an IF test for each $Var. then build the output string from the results.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't considered that. I'll try now, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome ... good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: I have stumbled upon a simple solution. Since in this case it technically doesn't matter which order the variables are in, throwing in a simple "|sort" before the -join solves the comparison problem (each variable comes in the format "ABC:123" and only the 123 changes). The question is still valid, though I will update it now.

Comment: simple solutions are very nice! [*grin*] since your data set is predictable, that is also a very to-the-point solution. [*grin*]